# List of all possible error messages that XDocument.Validate throws

Tags: xml, xml-validation

I am validating xml files against a single xsd schema specification.
I thought of producing some sort of Errors Distribution output report, which would group all errors by their type/category and indicate the percentage of the elements/errors that failed it.

For that, I need, ideally, the list of all possible error messages that XDocument.Validate throws.

Is this available anywhere (other than digging the source code recently made open) ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround (not perfect, but will work for most of the commonest errors) is, given that most of the errors come in the format "... - The errorCategory] constraint failed." - I am extracting the sub string that immediately follows the last occurrence of " - " in the error message, and subsequently taking out the 2nd word from that sub string, in case it starts with a capital letter.